# Terraform - How to get App Service object id for azurerm key vault access policy?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

Using Terraform, I am trying to add a keyvault access policy to an application (that is also created in Terraform), which requires an **object_it** (which is GUID) of that application. In ARM template it looks like this:

```
 "objectId": "[reference(variables('myAppResourceId'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]"
```

so Terraform needs the *principal id* there to be assigned to the *object_id*. If I use the value **"object_id = ${azurerm_app_service.myApp.id}"** like this:

```
  resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "pol1" {
  vault_name          = "${azurerm_key_vault.kv1.name}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_key_vault.kv1.resource_group_name}"

  tenant_id = "${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}"
  object_id = "${azurerm_app_service.myApp.id}"

  key_permissions = "${var.app_keys_permissions}"
  secret_permissions = "${var.app_secrets_permissions}"
}
```

then when I run apply command, I get the following error:

```
azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.pol1: "object_id" is an invalid UUUID: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+002F '/'
```

this is probably the id that looks like an url with a slash,so this does not work, since I need the GUID only.

---

I tried also a suggestion from [Terraform grant azure function app with msi access to azure keyvault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642793/terraform-grant-azure-function-app-with-msi-access-to-azure-keyvault), by using **object_id = "${lookup(azurerm_app_service.app1.identity[0],"principal_id")}"** for an app service instead of the function and I get an error:

```
 azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.appPolicy1: At column 43, line 1: list "azurerm_app_service.app1.identity" does not have any elements so cannot determine type. in:

${lookup(azurerm_app_service.app1.identity[0],"principal_id")}
```

---

could someone help me with this object_id please?

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you read the description for azurerm_key_vault_access_policy property [object_id](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault_access_policy.html#object_id), then you should know it could mean the web app principal Id.

And the **azurerm_app_service.myApp.id** that you put is not the principal Id, it's the app service resource Id. You should put the azurerm_app_service.myApp.identity.principal_id that associated with your web app. Take a look at the [Attributes of the App Service Resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#attributes-reference). Hope this will help you.

However, something not mentionned in the documentation is the need to specify an identity block in your app_service declaration.

```
identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }
```

If you don't specify it, you might get an empty list as identity attribute.

Comment: That was the problem that I had initially. The docs say:

 
You can access the Principal ID via: `${azurerm_app_service.test.identity.0.principal_id}` 
and the Tenant ID via:
`${azurerm_app_service.test.identity.0.principal_id}`



so, when I try getting principal id:
`object_id = "${azurerm_app_service.app1.identity.0.principal_id}"`


I gen the following error:
`* azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.appPolicy1: Resource 'azurerm_app_service.app1' does not have attribute 'identity.0.principal_id' for variable 'azurerm_app_service.app1.identity.0.principal_id'`

Comment: You could use the principal Id if you set it in the app service resource. Do you set it?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Is it that I should also create _azuread_service_principal_ and assign _application_id_ and then app1 will have identity.0.principal_id. Or do you mean that I should include _identity_ section in  _azurerm_app_service_ and include principal Id there?

Comment: What you say are the two ways that you can do it. I mean the second one. But I think they can all work for you.

Comment: Alright. it seems like adding `identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }` to azurerm_app_service did the trick and now `output "application_identity_principal_id" {
  value = "${azurerm_app_service.app1.identity.0.principal_id}"
}` shows the id. I think that will solve my problem. Thanks for pointing it out the explicit need for the identity assignment.

Comment: When trying to reference an App Service using its object_id in terraform KeyVault policy **azurerm_key_vault_access_policy**, this answer also fixes the following **Error: "object_id" isn't a valid UUID**